# Pixels not Aligned Correctly

Tags: java, graphics, 2d

I'm attempting to align my pixels for a game I am going to make, however, I can't seem to get them correct.
My frame is `500x500px` and I'm painting a `20x20` pixel at `250x 250y`, however it does not look center at all: (Can't embed image) http://puu.sh/5TkCa.png

I double checked that it was at `250, 250` using `g.fillRect(250, 250, 20, 20);`

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Draw it at `240, 240`. When you call `fillRect()` the coordinates you give it are to the corner of the rectangle.

From the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#fillRect%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29):

> The left and right edges of the rectangle are at x and x + width - 1. The top and bottom edges are at y and y + height - 1.

Comment: The top left corner of the rectangle will be at the coordinates you specify. That means if you draw it at 240, 240, then the 4 corners will be top left: 240, 240, top right: 259, 240, bottom right: 259, 259, and bottom left: 240, 259. So in order to fit the whole rectangle on the screen the limit would be 481, 481.

Comment: Wow that's confusing, but I think I get it. Thanks!